# Нужно решить парчу задач по структурам C++ , не могу понять каким образом. Кто может помочь,Хоть даже за плату

Tags: c++, структуры

Есть задачи, но их, по идее нужно реализовать при помощи структур. не хватает ума додумать , как.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: есть по моему специальные сайты, где  за плату напишут вам все что угодно. Один раз сделаю для вас исключение, но  не пытайтесь еще раз обращаться сюда с таким вопросом, это не тот сайт...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
unsigned even(unsigned i, int j)
{
    if (j > 0 && !(j & 1)) //j положительное и четное
        return i + j;
    return i;
}
int main()
{   
    unsigned N = 0;
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> v;
    //копируем в вектор N чисел, но  не больше 100, из cin
    copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin), N % 101, back_inserter(v));
    auto L = v.begin();
    while (*L & 1) ++L; // проходим нечетные
    auto r = v.rbegin();
    while (*r & 1) ++r;  // пропускаем нечетные с конца
    auto R = r.base();   // получаем нормальный итератор на следующий элемент     
    // накапливаем в обьект типа unsigned  результат функции    
    cout << accumulate(L, R, unsigned(), even);
    return 0;
}
```

и наслаждаемся результатом, а для выполнения программы время мизерное.
Если данные из файла, то имя файла заменит cin

Comment: но я невнимательно прочитал условие, нужно исправить